# Ruby | Problem with method for build pyramids

Tags: ruby, function, methods, integer

I already have a program that allows you to build a pyramid with "#" but I want to make a new file with methods. I don't understand why it doesn't work. I have already test lot of code. I even removed the 25 story loop.

```
puts "Salut, bienvenue dans ma super pyramide ! Combien d'étages veux-tu ?"

print ">"

etages = gets.chomp.to_i
espace = etages - 1
carre = 1

while etages > 25 
    puts "Réessayez ! La pyramide ne doit pas excéder 25 étages !"
    print "> "
    etages = gets.chomp.to_i
  end

etages.times do
    espace.times do
        print " "
      end
     espace -= 1
    carre.times do
        print "#"
        end
        carre += 2
        puts " "
    
    
end

def ask_etages
    puts "Salut, bienvenue dans ma super pyramide ! Combien d'étages veux-tu ?"
    print ">"
    etages = gets.chomp
    return etages
end

def full_pyramid
    espace = etages - 1
    carre = 1

    etages.times do
        espace.times do
            print " "
          end
         espace -= 1
        carre.times do
            print "#"
            end
            carre += 2
            puts " "
           
    end

        end
    

def perform
    ask_etages
    full_pyramid
end

perform
```

Comment: A note about a question's tags. Tags are used by readers to filter questions, generally to identify questions of interest but also to identify questions that are not of interest. I removed the Rails tag because this is a pure-Ruby question. Except for "ruby" the remaining tags do no harm but are unlikely to be used by readers to filter questions. For that reason I suggest there be only one tag, "ruby". Also, because of the "ruby" tag there is no need to include "Ruby" in the title.

Comment: I understand, sorry for this

Comment: Please explain what behavior you're expecting and what's actually happening. I don't recommend adding user interaction as part of a reproduction. If you have to add user interaction, please show a sample run that fails. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to pass the variable `espace` to your method `full_pyramid`, so you just need a small change.

Since `ask_etages` asks the user for an input (side note: use `puts` instead of `print`) then returns that value as integer you need to pass it to `full_pyramid`.

Do to so just define the method as:

```
def full_pyramid(etages)
  espace = etages - 1
  carre = 1
  etages.times do
    espace.times do
      print " "
    end
    espace -= 1
    carre.times do
      print "#"
    end
    carre += 2
    puts " "
  end
end
```

Then define `perform` as:

```
def perform
    full_pyramid(ask_etages)
end
```